# Average lifespan of objects

Tags: probability

I have $n$ hard drives. The life expectancy of any drive is $L(t) :\mathbb{N}\to[0,1]$ where $t$ is the number of years the drive is used. When a drive dies it gets replaced instantaneously.
I want to know the average life time of the drives after $u$ years.

Let $L(t)=\min(\frac{t}{10}, 10)$ for now.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: So, not really understanding what you're saying, or rather, it doesn't seem that solvable with what you've got here.  let me as you, if I use a drive for say, 7 years, what is the chance it will fail that year? if i use it for $n$ years?